# How to return the worksheet of an embedded chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Say I have a chart (or chartobject), is there any way I can access the worksheet given this chartobject.

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = some_chart_embedded_in_worksheet

Dim ws as Worksheet
'I want to know if there is a way to get the worksheet of the embedded chart
Set ws = cht.???
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
   msgbox Left(ActiveChart.Name, 6)
```

it will tell you the sheet name